# $ L^p $ and inequality

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem in Measure Theory.

I assume that I have to use Hölder's Inequality but I don't see how.

Let $ E $ measurable, $m(E)<+\infty$, $1<p<+\infty$ and $ f\in L^p(E)$.

Prove that, if $ 1\leq r \leq p $, then $ f\in L^r(E)$ and $\|f\|_r \leq \|f\|_p m(E)^{\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{p}} $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track, indeed Holder inequality is *all* you need to apply: 
$$
\|f\|_r^r = \int_E |f|^r = \int_E |f|^r\cdot 1
\le \Big(\int_E |f|^{r\frac pr}\Big)^{\frac rp}\Big(\int_E 1\Big)^{1 - \frac rp} = \|f\|_p^{\frac rp}m(E)^{1 - \frac rp}.
$$
Raising both sides to the power $\frac{1}{r}$ we obtain the desired inequality. Notice that here we used Holder's inequality with exponents $\frac pr$ and conjugate exponent $\frac{p}{p - r}$ (I have tacitly assumed that $r < p$, since otherwise there is nothing to prove).

Comment: Thanks! The book I am reading states that $ f \in L^p(E) $ and $ g \in L^q(E)$ are necessary conditions for Hölder and I was stuck. Clearly, they are not.

Comment: @Greg: You are welcome! Notice that those assumptions are verified in this case: the assumption $f \in L^p$ in the book here reads $|f|^r \in L^{\frac pr}$, which is satisfied since $f \in L^p$ by assumption. Same is true for $g = 1$ since the measure of the set is finite. Something that is worth mentioning is that the inequality is true even without those assumptions but it is meaningless since if, for example, $f \notin L^p$, then Holder's inequality would read $\int fg \le \infty$, which doesn't give much information.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$ \int_E |f|^p =\int_E 1|f|^{p} $$

Now what you want to do is to use the Holder inequality, so that, using as exponent for f    $  \quad  \frac{p}{r} \ \ $

$$ \int_E |f|^r \leq \left( \int_E 1^{} \right)^\frac{p-r}{r} ||f ||_p ^{p}$$